# Can I Replace Numpy with a Different Build?

Tags: python

I want to use OpenCV in Blender (2.77a), but trying to build it under Windows is incredibly frustrating.  I downloaded a pre-built version from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs, but it's not compatible with the numpy that comes with Blender:

```
>>> import cv2
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xa but this version of numpy is 0x9
```

I found that I can get around that by using a different pre-built version of numpy, but

1. I'm not sure what side-effects that might cause (is numpy used for anything in Blender itself?).
2. I'm not sure of the best way to override Blender's numpy.  Right now, I'm inserting the path to the new numpy at the beginning of sys.path.

Is there a better way to handle this?  How can I find out what API version of numpy is in the latest Blender release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I don't think it's used by Blender itself. Possibly certain add-ons do, though. You'll notice soon enough if something doesn't work any more ;-)
2. I think that's a pretty good way to go about it. It's not destructive, so you can always go back to the shipped numpy.

Comment: Thanks.  How would you go about adding the path?  Right now I have it in a script in the startup directory.  It looked like the environment variables added it to the end, so that didn't help.

Comment: You can `import sys` and then `sys.path.insert(0, path_to_your_numpy)`. Doing this in a script in the startup directory sounds fine to me.